# Installing nvidia-modprobe on Ubuntu 14.04 causes frozen splash screen on boot

Tags: cuda, drivers, nvidia

So for research I have to install CUDA 7.5 which only works with nvidia-352 and above, so I followed the recommended approach from this article:

[BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia - Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

My graphics card is Nvidia GeForce 750M, so I installed version 352.63. So far so good. But when I installed nvidia-modprobe because cuda needs it, right after rebooting I'm given the purple splash screen of death.

So naturally I reversed my last step: I purged nvidia-modprobe in recovery mode and restarted -- miraculously The splash screen disappeared. I didn't believe my luck so I recreated this problem multiple times, each time it points to nvidia-modprobe.

Since I need nvidia-modprobe for projects, but it causes error in booting, I can bypass the error by purging it before I restart. But where in god's green earth did this problem come from? I tried to find a solution but couldn't find any.

I see that when it installs nvidia-modprobe, it tries to use driver version 340, but I tried finding a matching 352 version in ubuntu software repository and couldn't find anything.

```
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-modprobe_340.24-1~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-modprobe (340.24-1~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-modprobe (340.24-1~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. My solution is:

1. Remove nvidia-modprobe.
2. Use this script: 
   http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#runfile-verifications.